# How to view only my mail box and not the shared ones

Tags: mail.app, email, search

I started a new job and the mail client has a lot of shared inboxes. How do I see the messages directed only at me? In other words, I'd like to filter out my own personal mail box.

I'm using Mac OSx 10.8.5 and the default mail app. If there's no way to select a specific mail box how can I filter out messages with my e-mail address in the to/cc/bcc field?

In the left column there's a MAILBOXES heading but only "Inbox" is beneath with no further selections.

[image: screenshot of Mail app]

In this screenshot I have `Chats` selected, which is empty, but if I go to `Inbox` there's a ton of stuff, not all of which is mine.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the left side of your Mail.app window?  I'm not exactly sure what your Mail setup is from your post, so hard to troubleshoot. :)  Make sure you remove any sensitive information from your screenshot.

Comment: @thankyour what program can I use to hide sensitive info?

Comment: Take a screen shot, open the PNG in Preview, and black out anything you don't want seen.  There are a lot of ways to do it, but that should be a quick and dirty way for you.

Comment: How many accounts are configured under Mail > Preferences > Accounts?

Comment: Is the account that's configured in Mail a shared account or something? Otherwise, just remove the account that's in there and add only your individual account. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand your question, but here is what I think it is.

You can create a New Smart MailBox (under the Mailbox Tab) that will automatically filter all your personal emails (addressed to you) and store them in to that mail box.

[image: smart mailbox]